# finding a complement of a subset

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B$ be a nonempty proper subset of a set $A$. Let $F$ be a field and let $V = F^A$.
Let $W$ be the subspace of $V$ consisting of all those functions $f \in V$ satisfying
$f (b) = 0 $ for all $b \in B$. Find a complement of $W $ in $V$.

Is this correct to say that the complement of $W$ is a subspace of $V$ such as $ U$consisting of all those functions $f\in V$ satisfying $f(b)\neq 0$ for some $b\in B$?

Comment: No. If $W$ is subspace of vector space $V$, the complement we are talking about here is subspace $W'$ of $V$ such that $V$ is direct sum of $W$ and $W'$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linear algebra, a complement of a subspace $W\subseteq V$ is usually another vector subspace $W'$ such that $V=W\oplus W'$. To be a direct sum like this, every vector in $V$ has to decompose uniquely as the sum of vectors in $W$ and $W'$. The only overlap can be the zero vector. A common way to achieve this if you have an inner product is an orthogonal complement.

So your choice of complement is not a vector subspace. For example it doesn't contain the zero vector. And it's not a complement in the direct sum sense. So I don't think it's what you want.

A better choice (but not necessarily the only one) for the complement of $W$ may be those functions $f\in V$ satisfying $f(a)=0$ for $a\in A\setminus B$. If $A$ is finite, then this is actually the orthogonal complement relative to the inner product given by $\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_{a\in A}f(a)g(a)$.